# Excel 2010 VBA to Hyperlink Active Cell to itself, so it would lead to it's exact location from when that cell is pasted and sent in Outlook e-mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, hyperlink

Objective: Excel 2010 - VBA to Hyperlink Active Cell to itself, so it would lead to it's exact  location on spreadsheet from when that cell is pasted and sent in Outlook e-mail.
I need to keep the contents of the Excel cell intact - keep displaying whatever I have in it not related to hyperlink etc. That cell will be e-mailed. Need to be able to click on cell from Outlook e-mail message and have that Hyperlink open the spreadsheet and select that exact cell location on that spreadsheet. 
The only element is missing is that Hyperlinking part. The VBA code I have below bugs out (yellow highlighting) the part with Hyperlinks.  Sorry if I'm not pasting code according to the rules - I probably am not understanding them.  Thanks for help!

```
Sub H_Link_Cell_to_Self
Dim path As String
Dim sheet As String
Dim cell As String
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
sheet = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
cell = Application.ActiveCell.Address
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(Active.Cell), "path” & “\“ & “sheet” & “\“ & “cell"
End Sub
```

Comment: Your last line of code has double quotes around your variables. It should be **ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(Active.Cell), path & “\“ & sheet & “\“ & cell**

Comment: @Twisty Put it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good with exception of the line that adds the hyperlink. Here you have your variables surrounded by double-quotes which is causing them to be interpreted as literal values instead of variables.

Try this instead:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(Active.Cell), path & “\“ & sheet & “\“ & cell
```

Comment: Tested macro with both versions of code below (only difference between, is without and with “Application.” upfront).  
Active.cell, path, sheet, cell – all recognize proper locations, however getting a “Run-time error ‘424’: Object required”

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(Active.cell), path & "\" & sheet & "\" & cell

    Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(Active.cell), path & "\" & sheet & "\" & cell